# Flutter Image Carousel Click and Zoom

Tags: flutter, carousel

I am new to Flutter and I am stuck doing image carousel that need to be able to zoomable. Because my images are posters.

Comment: Why down grade? I can't find it online. All I found are image carousel that can't be zoomable. If zoomable, we can't zoom to the whole image.

Comment: Can you provide code showing what you have or what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you @AlexMeuer. I provided code below as Answer (but it is still not ok yet).

Answer (score 0):

Now, in flutter, I found way to make image carousel which can be zoomed to highly when click. And there is another difficulty, after image is zoomed and Back button is clicked, app is closed. How can I manage the app to --> image zoomed -> Back button clicked -> show original image carousel again without closing app?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import './app_bar.dart';
    import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
    import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: GalleryExample(),
    );}}
    class Galleryimage extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: PhotoViewGallery(
              pageOptions: <PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions>[
                PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
              imageProvider: AssetImage("images/onegap.png"),
              heroTag: "tag1",
            ),
            PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                imageProvider: AssetImage("images/onehnan.png"),
                heroTag: "tag2",
                ),
            PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
              imageProvider: AssetImage("images/onesite.png"),
              heroTag: "tag3",
            ),
          ],
        ));}}
```